# Error converting assert.fail to async-await from functions not working

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am trying to convert some test codes to work using the async await syntax. The above portion code using async-await is not working while the lower portion code using then is working fine.

Can anyone advise me how I should correct the code to make it work? Thanks

**NOT WORKING**

```
it("transfers token ownership", async () => {
            tokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed();

            try {
              return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], "9999999999999999");
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("error ", error);
              assert(
                error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0,
                "Error message must contain revert"
              );
            }
          });
```

**WORKING**

```
it("transfers token ownership", function() {
    return DappToken.deployed()
      .then(function(instance) {
        tokenInstance = instance;
        return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 9999999999999999999);
      })
      .then(assert.fail)
      .catch(function(error) {
        // console.log("error", error);
        assert(
          error.message.toString().indexOf("invalid") >= 0,
          "error message must contain revert"
        );
        return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 250000, {
          from: accounts[0]
        });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works!

hope this will help someone else :)

```
 it("transfers token ownership", async () => {
    tokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed();

    try {
      await tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], "9999999999999999");
      assert(false);
    } catch (error) {
      assert(
        error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0,
        "Error message must contain revert"
      );
    }
  });
```